# How do you get a text box that becomes a pull down menu like in Yahoo Finance "Get Quotes"?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The first letter you enter creates a pull-down menu of all items in a database that start with that letter...

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) plugin?

Comment: Yup, that's the one. Thanks!

If I just have 3-5 words to complete against what would be the best way to get that dataset into autocomplete if I'm using PHP and can preload the data locally? i.e. how do I get the dataset so it looks like it's local to JS?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions), it seems you can use "local" data, directly into the JS code, ie without having to do an Ajax request to the server :

> **`autocomplete( url or data, [options] )`**
>
> `url or data` : String, Array
>   
> An URL pointing at a remote resource
>   or local data as an array.
>
> `options (Optional)` : Options
>   
> A set of key/value pairs that
>   configure the autocomplete. All
>   options are optional.

So, you need a way to convert the data you have on the PHP side to some Javascript array.

If you are using PHP >= 5.2, you can use the [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) function to do that.

For instance, you can have this kind of PHP code :

```
$data = array(
    'first',
    'second',
    'third',
);

$js_array = json_encode($data);

echo "var my_list = {$js_array};";
```

And the output you'll get looks like this :

```
var my_list = ["first","second","third"];
```

Which declares an initializes some Javascript array containing the results ;; up to you to put that kind of code where it belongs ;-)

Have fun !